# Spring Batch FlatFile Formatting

Tags: spring, spring-batch, flat-file

I've been doing some research, and can't seem to find any tutorials or articles discussing how to perform in depth formatting on an output file in Spring Batch.

For example, I want some output that looks like this

```
                     Header
---------------------------------------------
name             state          zip     phone
---------------------------------------------
name             state          zip     phone
---------------------------------------------
```

The problem here is writing the line separator between each row of records I print. Any ideas or tips on achieving this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FormatterLineAggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FormatterLineAggregator.html) for that. This `LineAggregator` uses the `java.util.Formatter` syntax, so you can use it to format each line with an appropriate format.

In regards to the header, you need to specify a [FlatFileHeaderCallback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileHeaderCallback.html) in which you write the header as needed.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)